# Author affiliation regarding

Tags: independent-researcher, affiliation

I completed my master's three months back. Currently, I am writing scientific articles with collobrations in which I use the previous educational affiliation. Is this correct or should I use my current address as affiliation? Please do help me in this regard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you aren't still a student (or faculty) you can't use your previous university. But "Independent Researcher" is really enough. Affiliation is there for identification purposes primarily.

But you should probably *not*  use your current address. It is likely to change and become useless. But it might also attract spammy mails that never go away.

Some might list "none" or "unaffiliated", but "Independent Researcher" seems better to me. It isn't uncommon, actually.

Comment: Can anyone please tag me a research article where the author has given his affiliation as an independent researcher.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I have just noticed research article mentioning independent researcher (eg. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S221169581830343X), I think also I can use this hereafter, and anyone this doubt in the mind can also use.